# How to break the loop flow-control in erlang on meeting a particular condition?

Tags: loops, recursion, erlang, break

I want to do a searching on a list in erlang programming language.
In erlang since we dont have loop construct, we use the recursion approach to do the loop.
However, I wanted to know how can we break this loop?
Say, once we find the desired element in the list.
Just like we use `break` in C language.

Answer (score 7):

```erlang
Elem = 3
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

elem_in_list(_Elem, []) -> false;
elem_in_list(Elem, [Elem | _Rest]) -> true;
elem_in_list(Elem, [_Head | Rest]) -> elem_in_list(Elem, Rest).
```

In the above code, we are looking for `3` in the given `List`. If we expand this out, it will look something like

```erlang
elem_in_list(3, [ 1 | [2,3,4,5,6]]) % Matches [_Head | Rest]
elem_in_list(3, [ 2 | [3,4,5,6]]) % Matches [_Head | Rest]
elem_in_list(3, [ 3 | [4,5,6]]) % Matches [Elem | _Rest]
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Justin's answer is the right one. You just stop the recursion right then and there.
But sometimes you're not writing the recursion yourself and you want to get away from an internal function (like a function in a fold). That's why Erlang has a non-local return keyword (namely: `throw`).
Let me show you:

Let's say you want to find the minimal positive integer in a list, using high-order functions. You can write your function as:

```
min_pos_int(List) ->
  lists:foldl(
    fun (Int, Min) when is_integer(Int), Int > 0, Int < Min -> Int
      ; (_, Min) -> Min
    end, infinity, List).
```

That will work, but... you know what the minimal possible positive integer is (i.e. `1`). So, if your list has `1` as an element, you can just break there, right?
OK. In Erlang you can do that with `catch` and `throw`, like this…

```
min_pos_int(List) ->
  catch lists:foldl(
    fun (1, _) -> throw(1)
      ; (Int, Min) when is_integer(Int), Int > 0, Int < Min -> Int
      ; (_, Min) -> Min
    end, infinity, List).
```

You can also use `try…catch…` syntax for this…

```
min_pos_int(List) ->
  try lists:foldl(
    fun (1, _) -> throw(1)
      ; (Int, Min) when is_integer(Int), Int > 0, Int < Min -> Int
      ; (_, Min) -> Min
    end, infinity, List)
  catch EarlyResult -> EarlyResult
  end.
```

You can check that it works by doing...

```
1> c(my_mod), timer:tc(my_mod, min_pos_int, [L]). % with catch & throw
{1,1}
2> c(my_mod), timer:tc(my_mod, min_pos_int, [L]). % without them
{2837520,1}
3> c(my_mod), timer:tc(my_mod, min_pos_int, [L]). % with try...catch
{7,1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement search by few approaches, but if you need find first match item in the list, you can try use lists generators with condition like below:

```
1> [X || X <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], X =:= 3].
[3]
```

So, I suppose you can try use it inside of some `case` block like:

```erlang
case [X || X <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], X =:= 3] of
  [_] -> find;
  []  -> not_found
end.
```